# Is the water mill when O-Ren and the Bride fight a homage to some movie scene?

Tags: kill-bill

In "Kill Bill", in the duel between O-Ren and the Bride, there is this small water mill (not sure how else to describe it) that is shown to be a part of the scene.

It seems like it is a homage to something - probably some Japanese movie, but I never saw a mention of it anywhere.

Is it a homage to some scene?

Comment: the video link in [this answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/238/96) might help you

Comment: Incidentally, that "water mill" is called a [Shishiodoshi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shishi-odoshi). It's depicted fairly often in Japanese media, so like many other aspects of the scenes with O-Ren there might not be any deeper reason for it than "it's a Japanese thing".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possibly a homage.

This is extremely similar to the end of the opening "You brought 2 horses too many" shootout scene in "Once upon a time in the West" - right after the shootout, we see this turning, squeaking windmill.

I've managed to find a [YouTube example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juwwCTBZOCQ&feature=player_detailpage#t=146s). The relevant portion is between the 2:25 and 2:45 marks.

*Please note that this is merely a possibility and purely my speculation, since I wasn't able to find that specific piece in any of the listings of homages, including those that list a couple of the ones from "Once upon a time in the West".*

Comment: Though your example is a wind mill.. but it's possible though :)

Comment: Tarantino is a huge fan of the Spaghetti Western genre, especially Once upon a time in the West, so that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The mill is more of a metaphor imo. Like the heroine, it repeatedly gets taken down only to bounce back time after time. 
  It adds to the scene's beauty exhibiting  QT's brilliance in creating a deep environment for the screen to get lost in.
  Homage it may be, but definitely a perfectly placed garnish.